# Relationship query orWhere overwrites other wheres

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.3

**Case**

Survey based on a few questions which returns `x` amount of apartments based on the results.

An apartment can have a static price (`price`), or a price range (`price_min` and `price_max`) - not all apartments have a static price yet so they are being defined by the price range (for example 900-1000 monthly rent)

**Problem**

Without the `orWhere([['price_min', '!=', null], ['price_max', '!=', null], ['price_min', '<', '900']]` everything works fine. Only the apartments which get past the `where` conditions are being returned; although when the `orWhere` condition is being added `all apartments with a price range` (so no `price`) are being returned, **no matter the previous conditions such as `floor` or `sun`**

**Code**

```
$selectedType = Type::where('slug', '=', $slug)->where('type', '=', 'studio')->with(['apartments' => function ($query) use ($request) {
    $query->where('status', '!=', 'sold');

    if ($request->floor == 'low') {
        $query->where('floor', '<', '5');
    } elseif ($request->floor == 'mid') {
        $query->where('floor', '>', '1')->where('floor', '<', '6');
    } elseif ($request->floor == 'high') {
        $query->where('floor', '>', '4');
    }

    if ($request->sun == 'morning_sun') {
        $query->where('sun', '=', 'morning');
    } elseif ($request->sun == 'evening_sun') {
        $query->where('sun', '=', 'evening');
    }

    if ($request->price == '1') {
        $query->where('price', '<', '900')->orWhere([['price_min', '!=', null], ['price_max', '!=', null], ['price_min', '<', '900']]);
    } elseif ($request->price == '2') {
        $query->where('price', '<', '999')->orWhere([['price_min', '!=', null], ['price_max', '!=', null], ['price_min', '<', '999']]);
    }
}])->first();
```

Comment: Personally (because I don't know laravel), I'd find it easier to consider the MySQL in isolation, and then leave it to you to convert that query into laravel

Comment: What datatype is `price_min`? Make sure that an empty string is different than null, so maybe the where should be `'price_min', '!=', ""`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to group the **orWhere** conditions. The following should do the trick:

```
if ($request->price == '1') {
    $query->where(function($q) {
      $q->where('price', '<', '900')->orWhere([['price_min', '!=', null], ['price_max', '!=', null], ['price_min', '<', '900']]);
    });
} elseif ($request->price == '2') {
    $query->where(function($q) {
      $q->where('price', '<', '999')->orWhere([['price_min', '!=', null], ['price_max', '!=', null], ['price_min', '<', '999']]);
    });
}
```